# Counterexamples for $G \times H$ isomorphic to $G$ implies $H$ trivial.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

I am interested in the following question:  Does $G \times H \cong G$ necessarily imply that $H$ is trivial?

In order to demonstrate it is not, I attempted to construct an example, but I am not entirely sure it is valid:

Let $G = \langle \mathbb{Z}; [a,b] \ (\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z})\rangle$.  Then $G \times G = \langle \mathbb{Z} \cup \mathbb{Z}; \ \{[a_1, b_1]\} \cup \{ [a_2, b_2]\} \cup \{[a_1,b_2]\}\rangle$, where my notation is intent to convey that the direct product presentation has the abelian relations from the "first" copy of G, the abelian relations from the "second" copy of G, and the required abelian relations which commute generators of the "first" copy with those of the "second" copy.

In this example, since our cardinalities are equal, $|\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$, and since this implies that commuting all elements of $G$ and commuting all elements of the same cardinality generating set $G \times G$ requires a bijection between the relator sets, then we should have a bijective group homomorphism $\phi : G \rightarrow G \times G$ so that we have isomorphism, but obviously $G$ is not trivial.  Therefore this provides the necessary counterexample to the original statement.

My first question is: is there anything wrong with this proof?  My second question is: if there is nothing wrong with the proof, is there a more standard way of constructing this type proof?  In general, it would seem that whenever you have isomorphic generating sets and isomorphic relator sets, then this should be enough to describe any number of counterexamples to the claim that $H$ must be trivial.  Is this true?  Finally, since direct products can be viewed as the products in the category Ab, and since all final objects must be isomorphic, would there be an easier way (or maybe just an insightful way) of construct this argument entirely in a category theoretic context?

Thanks!

Comment: if you took G to be an infinite product of Zs and H to be Z would that not be a counter example?

Comment: Indeed, $G\cong G\times H\cong G\times H\times H\cong\cdots$ so might as well define $G=H\times H\times\cdots$. Yes, your argument is correct. @MarkJoshi That's the example OP gave.

Answer (score 2):

It is a fact that $\Bbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$ as abelian groups, since they have the same dimension as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Although this is an interesting example, your answer provides neither a response to my first question regarding the accuracy of the proof I provided, nor a response to my second question regarding the general construction of such examples, nor to my last question.  Even if your example implies that what the construction I gave should also be correct, I cannot pick this as a best answer when you don't actually even answer any of my original questions!

Comment: Sorry-- I just read the title, which seems to ask for counterexamples to your conjecture.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on a lot of your notation, and judging from the lack of any response that isn't of the same form as mine I suspect I'm not the only one. Could you explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: What my notation was intending to define was that G is a group with generating set isomorphic to the integers (countable) and the only relations being the commutators.  I suppose, equivalently I could have defined G as the abelianization of the free group on the generating set $\mathbb

Comment: *$\mathbb{Z}$.  (sorry for the double comment; I don't seem to be able to edit my previously comment)

Comment: Okay, so you're talking about an abelian free group on a countable set of generators, which would be isomorphic to a countable direct product of copies of $\Bbb{Z}$, correct? Or rather the direct sum, actually.

Answer (score -2):

For finite groups, yes.  Consider the homomorphism from $G \times H$ to $G$ defined by
$$
(g, h) \mapsto g.
$$
This homomorphism is surjective and has kernel $H$.  Consequently, it is or is not an isomorphism accordingly as its kernel is or is not trivial.

For infinite groups, see Mark Joshi's comment above.

Comment: The hypothesis "$G\times H$ is isomorphic to $G$" doesn't specify what the putative isomorphism would look like. Your argument doesn't even make use of finiteness (note the projection $G\times H\to G$ would have potentially nontrivial kernel $H$ for infinite groups too).